# Compare images stored in mysql db

Tags: mysql, image, comparison, blob

I know I can store images in mysql as data type blob. Wandering if i can compare the blob values in my query?

E.g. select answer from mtTable where imageBlobValue = image010.

Here imageBlobValue and image010 data type is blob.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Well, while that should be theoretically possible, a more optimal way to handle this would be to store an image hash or some other unique identifier alongside the blob to use for query purposes.

You want to minimize the amount of times the database has to handle that blob in memory and the best way to do that is to have a suitable key to search on.

Comment: My current approach is to convert the image to md5 and compare.  Wandering if i can cut down this extra process of md5 conversion and directly ingest images to the the db. But i cannot afford further delays if it is slow to compare bolb data types.

Comment: I believe hashing the image for comparison is the best way to go. Using blobs will definitely slow down the process. You can try looking into faster hashing algorithms though due to the fact that cryptography is not your end goal. Check out: https://code.google.com/p/xxhash/